# Make index work on join to table variable

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, index-tuning, execution-plan

I a table with several columns, but the most importants are: `DocumentId(bigint)`, `StatusId(int)` and `ReceiveDateTime(datetimeoffset(3))`.

```
CREATE TABLE [DocumentInfo](
    [DocumentId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReceiveDateTime] [datetimeoffset](3) NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleting] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [StorageId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I also have a table variable which contains several rows (4 for now):

```
DECLARE @Tresholds TABLE
(
    DocumentStatusId int NOT NULL,
    Treshold datetime2 NOT NULL
);
```

I used indices on DocumentStatusId (is was a primary clustered key), and unique constraint (Treshold, DocumentStatusId), but query didn't use it, so I removed them.

My query looks like:

```
WITH TopOutdatedDocuments AS
(
    SELECT TOP (100000) di.DocumentId
    FROM [DocumentInfo] di WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN @Tresholds t ON di.StatusId = t.DocumentStatusId
    WHERE (ReceiveDateTime < @DocOldestTreshold OR (ReceiveDateTime < @DocNewestTreshold AND ReceiveDateTime < t.Treshold))
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [doc].[document] d (NOLOCK) WHERE d.ParentId = di.DocumentId)
)
```

The problem that the query plan always use index scan:
[image]

I tried to create an index for every permutation of these 3 columns, but it didn't use it anyway. `DocOldestTreshold` and `@DocNewestTreshold` are used to speedup a query, becuase they can be computed without a join. But it seems that engine doesn't use this opportunity.

How can I speedup a query? Its logical sense is that we have some tresholds for every `StatusId`, and if document is older than its treshold, it should be selected by this query.

Any help will be appreciated. I am now on SQL Server 2014. Order of `[DocumentInfo]`'s size is hundred millions of rows, typical size of `@Tresholds` is < 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your variables are always `NOT NULL`

```
WHERE  ( ReceiveDateTime < @DocOldestTreshold
          OR ( ReceiveDateTime < @DocNewestTreshold
               AND ReceiveDateTime < t.Treshold ) )
```

Is equivalent to

```
WHERE  ReceiveDateTime < @DocOldestTreshold
        OR ReceiveDateTime < LEAST(@DocNewestTreshold, t.Treshold)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
WHERE  ReceiveDateTime < GREATEST(@DocOldestTreshold, LEAST(@DocNewestTreshold, t.Treshold))
```

So if you have this index

```
CREATE INDEX ix
  ON [DocumentInfo](StatusId, [ReceiveDateTime])
```

And the following query

```
SELECT di.DocumentId
FROM   @Tresholds T
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(@DocNewestTreshold < t.Treshold, @DocNewestTreshold, t.Treshold)) CA1(Least)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(@DocOldestTreshold > CA1.Least, @DocOldestTreshold, CA1.Least)) CA2(Target)
       JOIN [DocumentInfo] di
         ON di.StatusId = t.DocumentStatusId
            AND di.ReceiveDateTime < CA2.Target
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM   [doc].[document] d (NOLOCK)
                            WHERE  d.ParentId = di.DocumentId)
```

It can do an equality seek on `StatusId` and a range seek on `ReceiveDateTime`